# html form non user generated inputs

Tags: html, forms

I am creating a html form that allows a user to edit the existing fields of a record in a database, they get to this form by pressing a button which links them to the correct form for that record depending on what button is clicked, basically what I want to do is if (say) button 1 is clicked then the information in the form (which may look like - name: age: ) will be defaulted, and the defaults change depending on what button is clicked, e.g. if I click on button 1 it could default like this - name: sean age: 18, but if I click on button 2 it could do this name: callum age: 17.

To do this I need to use a submit which I can use via:

```
<button name="UID" type="submit" value="some value">edit</button>
```

but because I am using 2 values, I need my submit buttom to use 2 values, could I do this? would it be something like

```
 <button name="UID" type="submit" value="some value", "another value">edit</button>
```

Also I would want to reference the values seperately so I would need two names but I do only want two buttons and because it isn't user generated information (it is generated via  a php script) I don't want to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="" method="get">
    Choose user:
    <button name="UID" type="submit" value="1">Sean</button>
    <button name="UID" type="submit" value="2">Callum</button>
</form>
```

IF you test it you will get `UID=1` when you click `Sean` and `UID=2` when you click `Callum`

Also

```
<button name="UID" type="submit" value="some value", "another value">edit</button>
```

Is wrong with `value` attribute, for such a need I would at least do:

```
<button name="UID" type="submit" value="'some value', 'another value'">edit</button>
```